Samsung: 970 EVO Plus vs 960 PRO
I have an "ASUS ZenBook Pro UX501VW-DS71T" laptop
I opened the laptop and the SSD is practically this Samsung at Amazon
It because the P/N is the same as "MZVPV512HDGL-00000". Therefore about its specs is indicated as follows:

M.2 Interface: PCIe 3.0 x4 lanes, up to 32Gb/s
256MB LPDDR2 DRAM Buffer Memory
3 Year Warranty, Supports Standard NVMe driver, APM and
L1.2 Power Saving Mode, End-to-End Data Protection, Support TRIM
Command, RoHS Compliant, Halogen-Free Compliance
Sequential Read:
2150MB/s, Sequential Write: 1500 MB/s, Random Read (QD=4): 300K IOPS,
Random Write (QD=4): 100K IOPS
Works with most motherboards and notebooks with a compatible M.2 PCIe interface slot. Includes
Z97/X99/Z120 motherboards. Not compatible with the MacBook, MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, or Mac Pro (see description for details)

Sadly Amazon does not sell anymore that item.
About Samsung I found these two:

Samsung MZ-V7S500B/AM 500GB 970 EVO Plus M.2 (2280)
Samsung 960 PRO NVMe M.2 512GB SSD (MZ-V6P512BW)

Even when the numbers are clearly different I am assuming that perhaps EVO Plus vs PRO would have an important difference to be considered. Thus if the budget is not a serious problem
Question

What of them is suggested and Why?

I did do a research on YouTube about NAND and exists the SLC, MLC, TLC and QLC types. But I did do realize that these 2 SSD of Samsung has the "V-NAND" term. Thus either vertical or 3d. Just in case for this old laptop
Extra question

Is safe for the Mobo install any of these SSD being V-NAND?

If you have a best suggestion than them, being Samsung and keeping the Gen3 x4 consideration, pls share the model.
Thank You

Just FYI, both of those SSDs are terrible value. My current favorite NVMe SSD is the Samsung 980, availible on Megekko for about €70 half terabyte and €105 for full terabyte. These are from my experience quite fast, use TLC (which is the longest lasting nand type that is still widely manufactured) and have a good price (at least where I live in the Benelux)
And about your bonus question, 3D NAND has been quite popular for a while now, but they don't stack chips, they just use the vertical space within the chip more efficiently, so don't worry about space constraints, the 980 is just standard size 2280 one layer. Your mobo isn't responsible for handling the stacking, the SSD controller (on the SSD itself) is responsible for that (unless you own an Mac Studio where the CPU is responsible for controlling the SSD, which is stupid)
